# Proportional scroll for DBGrid in delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, scroll, delphi-xe4, dbgrid

How can I have a proportional (vertical) scroll for DBGrid (Like DBAdvGrid in TMS Package )?!

I'm using MySQL (With InnoDB Engine).

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.delphi.database.desktop/xPWVgVxsYLI has a discussion of why this typically isn't possible. What database are you using? SQL-based databases typically don't know how many records there are without retrieving them all, which is very inefficient and results in tons of data being moved across the network. Without knowing how many records, you can't show the thumb proportionally, which is why it typically has three positions: top, bottom, and "we're somewhere in between".

Comment: But DBAdvGrid From TMS (and some other components)has a proportional Scroll!

Comment: You asked about `TDBGrid`, and I explained about `TDBGrid`. If you want to know how the other grid does it, read the source of that other grid. :-)

Comment: Does other Grids like DBAdvGrid enhance TDBGrid? :-?

Comment: Most are not based on TDBGrid at all, but are custom written. I don't use `DBAdvGrid`, so I can't tell you how they implemented it. You'd have to ask TMS.

Comment: If you do a `.last` and `.first` on the dataset after opening the table, doesn't tdbgrid then show you a proportional bar?

Comment: Hi Rik. Nope! Unfortunately this method does not work.